# iPhone:What is the version of Xcode to use for developing apps for iOS 4.2.1?

Tags: iphone

I am having the updated iOS 4.2.1 iPhone. I want to develop apps for that. I have Xcode 3.2.5 version now, but it shows upto only 4.2 device to select, doesn't show 4.2.1. What version of Xcode i should use for developing apps for this device? Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always use the latest stable version for development.

There is no dedicated version for 4.2.1, use what you have and let XCode collect the missing debug information from your device.

Comment: I am not getting it. Any app is not installing on this iPhone 4.2.1 using this Xcode. How can i install, debug and check the apps on this iPhone using Xcode 3.2.5? When i try to install the app thru Xcode, it says "No provisioned iOS device is connected".

Comment: OK. Xcode asking to collect the debug information as Mr.fluchtpunkt said. I have an another doubt, after collecting the debug information, will it ask for Reboot the device (or) not necessary to reboot? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently the latest stable version.